# how destroy jwt token from spring boot backend

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I want to destroy [jwt](/questions/tagged/jwt) token from [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) application.

Architecture is the following :

- front-end: react
- back-end : sring boot

I have to implement logout function. Now I developed the logout function in front-end and it removes the jwt token in redux storage but when I use the same jwt token before it removed from the front-end redux storage then  I can use that token form postman and I can access secured rest end points.

How to remove the jwt  in spring boot back-end.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, as your application is stateless, your Spring Boot app won't know when your client logout cause it never keep track of all the tokens it has issued/generated. (That's why it's called stateless :D)
The best practice here is to keep your JWT expire shortly. This way it become expired before someone try to reuse the token.

To make the user journey seamless, you can refresh JWT token in background to make sure user always stay login.

Comment: The refreshing part would require you to issue another token - this one, should be long lived and non-JWT. There are actually a bunch of different ways you can play around with refresh tokens. See [this blog](https://hackernoon.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-user-session-security-ee5245e6bdad) - it explains it quite well.

Answer (score 0):

You can flag tokens using a caching database such as Redis, so whenever you get a token you check if you've it in Redis, and sure to destroy it, just delete it from Redis.

- Add @PreAuthorize filter that get the token and check if it exists in Redis
- If it exists throw your exception
- If it doesn't exist store it and return the success response

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).